# Как найти создателя сервера discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

Я делаю команду для информации про сервер
Я использую ctx.guild.owner что бы найти создателя сервера,но когда использую команду вместо создателя пишет None

````
@bot.command()
async def si(ctx):

    role_count = len(ctx.guild.roles)
    list_of_bots = [bot.mention for bot in ctx.guild.members if bot.bot]
    staff_roles = ["Owner", "Head Dev", "Dev", "Head Admin", "Admins", "Moderators", "Community Helpers", "Members"]
        
    embed2 = discord.Embed(timestamp=ctx.message.created_at, color=ctx.author.color)
    embed2.add_field(name='Название сервера', value=f"{ctx.guild.name}", inline=False)
    embed2.add_field(name='Создатель сервера', value=f"{ctx.guild.owner}", inline=False)
    embed2.add_field(name='Уровень верификации', value=str(ctx.guild.verification_level), inline=False)
    embed2.add_field(name='Высшая роль', value=ctx.guild.roles[-1], inline=False)

    for r in staff_roles:
        role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name=r)
        if role:
            members = '\n'.join([member.name for member in role.members]) or "None"
            embed2.add_field(name=role.name, value=members)

    embed2.add_field(name='Количество ролей', value=str(role_count), inline=False)
    embed2.add_field(name="Количество участников ", value=ctx.guild.member_count, inline=False)
    embed2.add_field(name='Создано', value=ctx.guild.created_at.__format__('%A, %d. %B %Y @ %H:%M:%S'), inline=False)
    embed2.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.guild.icon_url)
    embed2.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    embed2.set_footer(text=bot.user.name, icon_url=bot.user.avatar_url)
    

    await ctx.send(embed=embed2)```
````

Comment: Вероятно, вы не выдали боту намерения для работы с участниками. Почитать что это такое и как их выдать можно [**здесь**](https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/discord-py.md#%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

Comment: Выдал.Вот смотрите [тут](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/803704689119723540/923155537334513674/unknown.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DOCS](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=owner#discord.Guild.owner)

```
@bot.command()
async def owner(ctx):
    await ctx.send(ctx.guild.owner.mention)
```

Answer (score 1):

Создателя сервера discord зовут Джейсон Цитрон.
Найти его очень просто: [Jason Citron](https://twitter.com/jasoncitron)